# Cannot reuse svg because of viewport

Tags: svg

I created an svg for a polyline with two circles on either end like this:

`<svg width="42px" height="42px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <g>
        <circle cx="21px" cy="21px" r="21px" fill="black"/>
        <g>
            <polyline points="20 30 15 20 25 15 20 7" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
            <circle cx="20" cy="30" r="2.2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
            <circle cx="20" cy="7" r="2.2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>`

I wish to reuse the polyline and the circles like this:

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20px" height="20px" version="1.1">
   <g transform translate=(-30,-30)>
            <polyline points="20 30 15 20 25 15 20 7" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
            <circle cx="20" cy="30" r="2.2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
            <circle cx="20" cy="7" r="2.2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
        </g> 
</svg>`

However the coordinates for the points are at `30` and so on. How do I modify this svg for reusability. Which units should I use when specifying svg images.

Comment: for SVG reusability, use the `<symbol>` element along with `<use>`. then  you could also apply different styles/attributes to your shapes.  not sure what else you're asking about the viewport. clarify?

Comment: @Uzi I need to reuse this as a smaller image of size `20px X 20px` which I embed in a sidepanel. Some of the coordinates here are larger than that. Is there a way to define the svg in a pixel independent way?

Comment: pixels are pretty fixed. but i don't think independently is what you need, because you want to reuse parts of the code, the shape better have a coordinate system so it can scale good. have a [look](https://jsfiddle.net/bozz1/8ejy8c96/3/)

Comment: @Uzi I have two use cases for svg, one is to use them as `background-image` in css and the other is to add them as html, can i do a `<use href="#inner"/>` in the css after defining them in the `html`.

Comment: so for inline svg with fixed pixel size, see the example from my last comment. but to use the svgs as a css background you'll have to save each shape as a separate svg file and use that 
as a background-image. a symbol can't be a background image because it is not actually rendered. also i think `<use href>` won't work, it's `<use xlink:href>`